# Jenn-Air Dishwasher - Red "Add Salt" and "Drying" Lights at End of Cycle

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

I have a Jenn-Air dishwasher, model JDB9800CWP2. It seems to be working normally, except that at the end of the cycle, the **Add Salt** and **Drying** lights are dimly glowing red. It has not done this before, except that it would sometimes have the "Add Salt" light lit when I *did* need to add salt.

This issue with both the Add Salt and Drying lights glowing red started about 1.5 weeks ago, just after we started experiencing a leak that went unnoticed for a few days. At the time, the dishwasher was leaking and not completing its drying cycle.

We just had the leak repaired - a component attached to the dishwasher basin was what was leaking, and the repair person replaced the whole basin. We've used the dishwasher a few times, and it seems to be working normally, except for these odd indicator lights at the end of the cycle. **What do they mean?**

For clarity, the dishes *are* dry at the end of the cycle, and the salt container is full to the brim.

Comment: Add salt??  Does that make it taste better? Never heard of that.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, some dishwashers use salt to "soften" the water and help prevent spots on the dishes at the end of the cycle. I don't have hard water, but even still, the built-in water softener makes a positive difference.